# horizontal scroll bar issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to display an horizontal scrool bar on this table, the problem isthat also I forced the scroolbar's display, it won't work, like if there is no reason why it has to appeare.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3KUk.png

I am using angular materials components; this is the whole CSS and a part of code of the app

```
<div class=" ng-clock docs-homepage-promo"></div>
    <div _ngcontent-c9="" class=" ng-clock docs-homepage-bottom-start" >
       <table> . . . </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

CSS

```
.docs-homepage-promo[_ngcontent-c9] {
align-items : center;
display : flex;
flex-direction : column;
padding : 16px;
}
.docs-homepage-promo[_ngcontent-c9] h2[_ngcontent-c9] {
font-size : 25px;
font-weight : 400;
margin : 0 0 16px 0;
padding : 0;
}
.docs-homepage-promo[_ngcontent-c9] p[_ngcontent-c9] {
font-size : 16px;
font-weight : 400;
line-height : 28px;
margin : 0 0 24px 0;
padding : 0;
}
.docs-homepage-promo-desc[_ngcontent-c9], .docs-homepage-promo-img[_ngcontent-c9] {
width : 50%;
}
.docs-homepage-promo-img[_ngcontent-c9] {
text-align : center;
}
.docs-homepage-promo-desc[_ngcontent-c9] {
line-height : 2;
display : flex;
flex-direction : column;
justify-content : center;
}
.docs-header-start[_ngcontent-c9], .docs-homepage-bottom-start[_ngcontent-c9] {
text-align : center;
margin : 60px 0;
}
@media (max-width:720px) {
.docs-header-section[_ngcontent-c9] {
padding-top : 15px;
}
.docs-header-start[_ngcontent-c9], .docs-homepage-bottom-start[_ngcontent-c9], .docs-homepage-row[_ngcontent-c9] {
margin : 15px 0;
}
}
```

Comment: the parent of the table element should have setted width and should has set overflow-x: auto

Comment: I think we wrote that at almost precisely the same moment, @LPZadkiel. Please excuse what looks like plagiarism below - I can assure you it is coincidence rather than that.

Comment: well i post just a comment, you post a full answer so they are kind of different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest your `<table>` element inside a `<div>`.

Then, you only need to add two CSS declarations to your `<div>`:

1. Apply a `max-width`
2. Apply `overflow-x: auto`

**Working Example:**

```css
table, th, td {
min-width: 80px;
padding: 3px;
border: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.table-container {
max-width: 300px;
overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">

<table>

    <thead>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>
</div>
```